# What does "webs" refer to?

Tags: publishing-site

Just a quick question on terminology...

Reading around the web on SharePoint I see a lot of people refering to "webs", but can't seem to find a description of what that refers to.

Based on the context I see it in I am guessing that it is in reference to sites/subsites somewhere in a Publishing collection, but that's just a guess really.

So.. what are "webs"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code, sites are represented by the class SPWeb and site collections are represented by SPSite. People, mainly developers, sometimes refer to sites as webs as a result of this.

Comment: The reason for the weird naming (that always confuses newcomers to SharePoint development) is backward compatibility. Back in SharePoint 2003 you had Microsoft SharePoint Portal Server 2003 as one product and Windows SharePoint Services as another (free) product. In WSS a sub-site was called a web and SPWeb in the object model. To make confusion even bigger, in Portal Server it was called an Area. The two object models were merged in SharePoint 2007 but due to backwards compatibility the naming was kept. Be aware that there also are SPWebCollections and SPSiteCollections

Comment: Just to be accurate it's SPSite and SPWeb (no plurals). 'Web' referring to sub sites is remnants from SharePoint 2003 terminology and it's not going anywhere because it's made it's way into SP2010 too. And just so we're all totally confused, there's SPSiteCollection which is a collection of site collections. Oh, and it's not just publishing sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it refers to Sites